# How to implement hit counting on google cloud storage files?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using app engine, and want to have a service that can generate custom images. I need to count the number of times the image has been served.

If I use google cloud storage, is there a way to get statistics on # of times served? Or would I have to proxy image requests through my app engine instance to do the counting? (that would be bad for performance I imagine?)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to enable GCS access logs. If you do so, GCS will, once per hour, compile a history of all accesses (inserts, gets, etc) of objects in your bucket as an hourly report, which you could then use to tabulate a total number of reads.

The downside to this approach is that your hit counter will only update every hour or so.

The instructions for enabling access logs are here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

Another option would be to serve those images through app engine, as you mentioned.

Comment: Also I just noticed that I was totally wrong and access logs are hourly, not daily.